# Is there a name for the type of noun is produced by adding the sufix 'ness' to an adjective?

Tags: nouns

Is there a name for the type of noun is produced by adding the suffix 'ness' to an adjective?

For example: Greedy - greediness

lonely - loneliness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> abstract nouns expressive of quality or state

from [plain text English dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?other=web1913&w=-ness)

> -ness
>   () A suffix used to form abstract nouns expressive of quality or state; as, goodness, greatness.

You can also compare to other definitions of the suffix [-ness](http://www.onelook.com/?w=-ness&ls=a)

Answer (score 5):

**Quality nouns** are nouns derived from adjectives. This wouldn't apply exclusively to those with the suffix -ness, but it would include them.

Comment: Not only quality, but also state or condition.